# Windows 10 Universal App - unknown JSON to table (C#)

Tags: c#, json, win-universal-app

I making a Windows 10 Universal App to connect to my database and display the table. I build sort of a API on my server that if called it returns mysql table data in json. Now, this received json data wont be always the same, so I want to display whatever table from my database on my server, by record. So that it will show only one record at the time, and when you press forward it will go to the next record. I can figure this out on my own(the buttons). But I don't know how to deserialize the unknown json data (which will be always different from table to table) and display it on table by record. I tried the `Dictionary<>` deserialize but it gave me an error, that the received string json must be a json object, which I later converted it to but it still wasn't working. I doing this just for learning and personal project. If anyone know's a solution it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

@David, I suggest you using the JSON.NET library to de-serialize the JSON string to Dictionary.
You can easily add a JSON.NET reference from the NuGet in Visual Studio.

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";

Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Comment: I get "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"label\":\"Home\",\"title\":\"Home Page\",\"header\":\"Welcome to my dynamic test site\",\"body\":\"This is the home page.\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"label\":\"About\",\"title\":\"About Me\",\"header\":\"About Davix\",\"body\":\"<img style=\\\"float:right;width:75%;height:75%;\\\" src=\\\"\\/images\\/ProfileMask.png\\\">\\r\\n This is the about me page.\"}]" . Now it say's me that I must either convert this to a JSON array or JSON object. If I convert it to JSON array I assum it would be more easy later to switch betwen record's becuase I'm more familiar wirh arrays.

Comment: In C# I get "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"label\":\"Home\",\"title\":\"Home Page\",\"header\":\"Welcome to my dynamic test site\",\"body\":\"This is the home page.\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"label\":\"About\",\"title\":\"About Me\",\"header\":\"About Davix\",\"body\":\"<img style=\\\"float:right;width:75%;height:75%;\\\" src=\\\"\\/images\\/ProfileMask.png\\\">\\r\\nThis is the about me page.\"}]" which is a incorrect syntax

Comment: But in browser it's displayed like this [{"id":"1","label":"Home","title":"Home Page","header":"Welcome to my dynamic test site","body":"This is the home page."},{"id":"2","label":"About","title":"About Me","header":"About Davix","body":"\r\nThis is the about me page."}] which is a correct syntax. So why does it in c# add \ beetwen :" and {" and ," ?

Comment: Ok, now I converted the JSON string to a dynamic object, and now the JSON is in the correct syntax. Now how do I display this in  a table?

Comment: '\' is a escape character in C#, ’“‘ is a reserved character, you need to use '\"' to express it in a C# string.

Comment: As I said, the syntax is right now, now that's the type dynamic. Here's the value: {[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "label": "Home",
    "title": "Home Page",
    "header": "Welcome to my dynamic test site",
    "body": "This is the home page."
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "label": "About",
    "title": "About Me",
    "header": "About Davix",
    "body": "<img style=\"float:right;width:75%;height:75%;\" src=\"/images/ProfileMask.png\">This is the about me page."
  }
]} Now how do I show this in a table bye record?